# Creating an exact json file by using php

Tags: php, json

I need to write the following output in PHP:

> var data = { "count": 1,
>   "elements": [{"id": 1, "title": "title123", "url": "x123.php", "file_url": "x124.jpg"}]}

I have tried:

```
$txt = 'var data = { "count": 1,"elements": ';
$txt = $txt + '[{"id": 1, "title": "title123", "url": "x123.php", "file_url": "x124.jpg"}';
    $something = json_encode($txt);
    echo $something;
    //
    $something = print_r($txt);
    echo $something;
    //
    $something = print_r(json_decode($txt));
    echo $something;
    //
    ob_start;
    var_dump($txt);
    $something = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $something;
```

I also have tried this:

```
$txt = '?var ?data ?= { "count": 1,"elements":';
for ($x = 0; $x <= strlen($txt); $x++) {
    $neso = substr($txt,$x,1);
    if ($neso != "?") {
    echo "+" + $neso + "+" + $x;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can not get any solution. All I get is 0 (zero) or 1 (one).

How can I get this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you generate json. PHP has absolutely NO clue what Javascript is - it's just plain text as far as PHP is concerned. When you do your `$txt = 'var...'`, and encode that, you're producing a json representation of the **STRING** you produced in php, which means your json will become

```
"var data = {\"count\": etc...}"
```

and now the JSON you **ALREADY** had in there is escaped, and no longer json - it's just a plaintext string.

What you want is something more like:

```
$php_array = array(
   'count' => 1,
   'elements' => array(
       array('id' => 1, 'title' => etc...)
   )
)

$javascript = 'var txt = ' . json_encode($php_array) . ';';
```

Note that your `echo "+" + $neso + "+" + $x;` is utterly useless. `+` in PHP does mathematical addition. You're trying to do string concatenation, for which the operator is `.`.

Comment: Welcome and, Well i must say thanks to you for your service on SO sir. @MarcB

Answer (score 2):

Learn about the structure of arrays, objects, and how the same thing is written in JSON.

To create a real json with PHP, the best way would be the following:

- create an array with the actual data
- json encode it
- pass it on

What will then be "echoed" if you try, will be the contents inside the first {}.

I would start by doing:

```
$data = array(
'count' => 1,
'elements' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'title123',
            'url' => 'x123.php',
            'file_url' => 'x124.jpg',
            ),
);
```

then: echo json_encode($data); or return $json_encode($data), to pass the data on.